# htaccess Content-Security-Policy/CSP headers blocked

Tags: .htaccess, header, blocked, content-security-policy

I am trying to set the `Content-Security-Policy/CSP headers` in the `.htaccess` file. But, its getting blocked for some reason in both `development` and `production` environments.

The same thing is happening for the `.css` and other sources like images.

```
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header add Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' http://*.google.com https://*.google.com https://*.googleapis.com"
...
```

[image]

I have already tried googling for the solution, but so far no luck.

Comment: The error message in the picture says the script is being blocked by the CSP and it quotes the CSP you say you are trying to set. The CSP is **not** being blocked. You’ve just written one that doesn’t allow your script.

Comment: Thank you for the insight @Quentin. But, how can I fix this issue, I am not good at htaccess configs and even after a lot of tries the problem is still standing.

Comment: The last sentence of the error message tells you how to fix it! (Or you could avoid using inline scripts as that is the type most at risk from XSS attacks that a CSP is designed to protect you from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

I had to define all the base urls and specific paths of the external resources with `http` and `https` protocol. Along with the `self` to allow all the files of the application and `unsafe-inline` for running the inline scripts written on the page.

```bash
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  ...
  Header add Content-Security-Policy "\
    default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://translate.googleapis.com http://translate.googleapis.com ...; \
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.gstatic.com ...; \
    img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google-analytics.com http://www.google-analytics.com ...; \
    font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.gstatic.com ...; \
    ...;"
</IfModule>
```

***Please note:***

1. Using `unsafe-inline` is considered a security threat.
2. Try to use the specific url(s) if you are not requesting the multiple files from the same source.

I hope this will help someone in need.